# Completely disabling password reset/recovery

Tags: plugins, password

I have a Wordpress multisite. One of the sites has two users: me and the enduser.
There are multiple password reset attempts for the enduser, not initiated by him.

I block the IP in the firewall of the hosting server, but the attempts keep coming from different IP's.

Every time this happens the endusers gets en e-mail, and he's concerned about security.

So, I want to completely disable password recovery. Googling this returns a lot of howto's, but for some reason, none of them work on my system.

What I tried:

- Installing (and activating network-wide) the plugin Disable Password Reset by H3llas. Result: nothing changed. Password reset still works.
- Installing Plainview Protect Passwords, blocking password reset for all users. Result: nothing changed. Password reset still works.
- Editing functions.php of the child-theme of the site of the end user with below code:

  ```
  function disable_password_reset() { 
                return false;
                }
  add_filter ( 'allow_password_reset', 'disable_password_reset' );

  function remove_lostpassword_text ( $text ) {
       if ($text == 'Lost your password?'){$text = '';} 
          return $text; 
       }
  add_filter( 'gettext', 'remove_lostpassword_text' );
  ```

  Result: nothing changed. Password reset still works.
- Editing functions.php with above code for the child-theme of the main site. Result: nothing changed. Password reset still works.

After each step I cleared the cache of WP Super Cache and my browser.

Any idea why non of these seem to work on my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a multisite you'll have to put the disable password filter in a mu-plugin. Create a file in wp-content/mu-plugins with:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'allow_password_reset', '__return_false' );
```

That should completely disable password recovery. It will affect all sites, not just that one customer's: if that's not what you intended you'll have to add logic here to restrict it to that one user e.g. by name, or by checking for permissions / roles on that customer's site, or by a flag in user meta.

Comment: I'm a bit hazy on the details but I guess the login page (and hence password reset mechanism) doesn't run in the context of any one blog, and so won't load any theme or plugins either, I presume if your network-wide disable password reset plugin didn't work. But it will load mu-plugins.

Comment: That worked! I didn't know about mu-plugins.

I added the below code, to also hide the link on the login page.


              
add_filter ( 'allow_password_reset', 'disable_password_reset_mu' );

function remove_lostpassword_text_mu( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {
     if ($untranslated_text == 'Lost your password?')
     {
         return '';
         
     } 
    return $translated_text; 
}
     
add_filter( 'gettext', 'remove_lostpassword_text_mu', 999, 3 );